# Как задать стиль окну если контрол определен в отдельной библиотеке?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть WPF User Control Library (.NET Framework) WPFLib, там определен Window

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WPFLib {
    public class Window : System.Windows.Window {
        static Window() {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Window), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Window)));
        }
    }
}
```

AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly:ThemeInfo(
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, //where theme specific resource dictionaries are located
                            //(used if a resource is not found in the page,
                            // or application resource dictionaries)
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly //where the generic resource dictionary is located
                                    //(used if a resource is not found in the page,
                                    // app, or any theme specific resource dictionaries)
)]
```

Themes/Generic.xaml

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type local:Window}"
    TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <AdornerDecorator>
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </AdornerDecorator>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Window.ResizeMode"
                Value="CanResizeWithGrip">
            <Setter Property="Template"
                    Value="{StaticResource WindowTemplateKey}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

и WPF App где

```
<wpflib:Window x:Class="WPFHost.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:wpflib="clr-namespace:WPFLib;assembly=WPFLib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Button VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Button"/>
</wpflib:Window>
```

Themes/Generic.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFHost"
    xmlns:wpflib="clr-namespace:WPFLib;assembly=WPFLib">


    <Style x:Key="{x:Type wpflib:Window}"
    TargetType="{x:Type wpflib:Window}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="Green"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type wpflib:Window}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <AdornerDecorator>
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </AdornerDecorator>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Window.ResizeMode"
                Value="CanResizeWithGrip">
                <Setter Property="Template"
                    Value="{StaticResource WindowTemplateKey}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>


</ResourceDictionary>
```

AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: ThemeInfo(
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, //where theme specific resource dictionaries are located
                                    //(used if a resource is not found in the page,
                                    // or application resource dictionaries)
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly //where the generic resource dictionary is located
                                            //(used if a resource is not found in the page,
                                            // app, or any theme specific resource dictionaries)
)]
```

При запуске окно красное т.е. WPF взял стиль у Generic WPFLib. Мне нужно чтобы в WPFLib был стиль по умолчанию но и в WPFHost я имел возможность переопределять его. Как подобное сделать?

Comment: Вы хотите переопределить стиль окна приложения?  По коду больше на это похоже.
В ```UserControl``` вид вы можете настроить какой захотите, а касательно окон Window, создаете xaml со стилем в словаре ресурсов и используете как стиль где вам угодно.

Comment: @xellan если поставить стиль в WPFHost где Background = Green в словарь всеравно окно будет красное

Comment: @xellan возможно будет работать если задать Style непосредственно окну но мне нужно чтобы работало наследование

Comment: окна подобные mainwinow наследуются от window что упрощает работу так как все свойства и т.п уже сделаны. И вы работаете в wpf ваша часть не должно задаваться и быть жестко связанной кодом.

Answer (score 1):

Как мы можем сделать для окон Window, пример
`WindowStyle.xaml`

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    x:Class="Telebine.Styles.WindowStyle.WindowStyle"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style x:Key="TopPanel" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F1F1F1"/>
        <Setter Property="WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#EAEAEA"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
            <Setter.Value>
                <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="30"
                              CornerRadius="8"
                              GlassFrameThickness="-2"
                              NonClientFrameEdges="None"
                              ResizeBorderThickness="5"
                              UseAeroCaptionButtons="True" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                    <Border x:Name="Title" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <AdornerDecorator Grid.Row="1">
                                <ContentPresenter/>
                            </AdornerDecorator>
                            <Grid Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Background="#F1F1F1">
                                <StackPanel x:Name="Buttons" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                                    <Button Name="btnMinimize" Width="45" Style="{StaticResource TopPanel}"  Click="MinimizeClick">
                                        <Button.Content>
                                            <Viewbox Width="12" Height="2">
                                                <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.8"  StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" Data="M11 1L1 0.999935"></Path>
                                            </Viewbox>
                                        </Button.Content>
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button Name="btnRestore" Width="45" Click="MaximizeRestoreClick">
                                        <Button.Style>
                                            <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource TopPanel}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                                                <Grid>
                                                                    <Border x:Name="Normal" BorderBrush="#000000"  BorderThickness="1" Width="11" Height="11"></Border>
                                                                    <Viewbox x:Name="Maximized" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="12" Height="12">
                                                                        <Grid>
                                                                            <Path Stroke="#000000" StrokeThickness="1"
                                       Data="M8.77778 8.77778H11V1H3.22222V3.22222M8.77778 8.77778V3.22222H3.22222M8.77778 8.77778V11H1V3.22222H3.22222"></Path>
                                                                        </Grid>
                                                                    </Viewbox>
                                                                </Grid>
                                                            </Border>
                                                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WindowState, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" Value="Maximized">
                                                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="Normal"></Setter>
                                                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="Maximized"></Setter>
                                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#EAEAEA"/>
                                                    </Trigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </Button.Style>
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button Name="btnClose" Background="#F1F1F1" Width="45" Click="CloseClick"  WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True">
                                        <Button.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F1F1F1"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                                            <Border x:Name="root" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                                                <Viewbox Width="14" Height="12">
                                                                    <Grid>
                                                                        <Path x:Name="s1" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.8" StrokeStartLineCap="Round"  StrokeEndLineCap="Round" 
                                       Data="M1.3999 1.60447L10.3999 10.1951"></Path>
                                                                        <Path x:Name="s2" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.8" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" 
                                      Data="M10.2003 1.40485L1.60034 10.3955" Cursor=""></Path>
                                                                    </Grid>
                                                                </Viewbox>
                                                            </Border>
                                                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F14C4C" TargetName="root"/>
                                                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FFFFFF" TargetName="s1"></Setter>
                                                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FFFFFF" TargetName="s2"></Setter>
                                                                </Trigger>
                                                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                            </Style>
                                        </Button.Style>
                                    </Button>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="WindowState" Value="Maximized">
                            <Setter TargetName="Title" Property="BorderThickness" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.WindowResizeBorderThickness}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

`WindowStyle.cs` code behavior

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace Telebine.Styles.WindowStyle
{
    public partial class WindowStyle : ResourceDictionary
    {

        private void CloseClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var window = (Window)((FrameworkElement)sender).TemplatedParent;
            window.Close();
        }

        private void MaximizeRestoreClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var window = (Window)((FrameworkElement)sender).TemplatedParent;
            if (window.WindowState == WindowState.Normal)
            {
                window.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
            }
            else
            {
                window.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            }
        }

        private void MinimizeClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var window = (Window)((FrameworkElement)sender).TemplatedParent;
            window.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
        }
    }
}
```

Использование
App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/WindowStyle/WindowStyle.xaml" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Постолько поскольку в `WindowStyle.xaml` не задан ключ для стиля, стиль для окон Window будет применяться ко всем окнам, во всем приложении. И изменить стиль уже можете как вам угодно. В часть code behavior не имеет слысла лезть, так как во view есть все что вам нужно

Comment: повторил, в дизайнере окно серое но при запуске стандартное белое т.е. стиль не применился

Comment: @MikeWaters вы что то сделали не так. https://skr.sh/sNlIvhde3Tv на скриншоте видно что стиль окна не похож на стандартный.  А как его настроить, выбор за вам.  Одна из причин почему не сработал код, у вас в вопросе написано про ```NET Framework``` попробуйте на net core повторить действия

Comment: @MikeWaters вы хотите сделать сделать кастомную тему и использовать её из библиотеки? По описанию у вас это получилось, проблема в том что вы не можете переопределить стиль для окна в основном приложении?

Comment: именно, в .NET 6 также не переопределился стиль, я так понимаю это потому что TargetType не определяет стиль для дочерних классов но что интересно, стиль из библиотеки применился)

Comment: @MikeWaters ```стиль из библиотеки применился``` измените в исходном коде библиотеки цвет фона на зеленый к примеру и вы увидите что ваш стиль не применился на самом деле. И вы создали стиль в первом примере Themes, во втором вы уже Custom Control создали. Но используете не правильно, то что вы создали под сомнением что будет работать корректно. И с библиотеки всё таки вы хотите стиль использовать или вы хотите кастомное окно создать?

Comment: @MikeWaters если вы хотите кастомное окно, то нет никакого смысла его делать если нужна только визуализация вида, представление стиля  ```Custom Control``` обычно используют где нужна встроенная логика кода, которую view не может дать. Завтра напишу пример.

Comment: @MikeWaters путём проб у меня не вышло полностью все шаблоны переопределить, их копии создаются не все. А писать в одном стиле не красиво. Какая ваша конечная цель, для чего это нужно? Можно в стиль пробросить dp свойства и ими стили задавать, расширить представление. Например
     ```<Style x:Key="r" TargetType="Window" BasedOn="{StaticResource CustomWindowStyle}">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>
         <Setter Property="local:WindowStyleDP.BackgroundCaption" Value="Orange"></Setter>
     </Style>``` здесь я наследовал стиль, изменил цвет заголовка и фона

Answer (score 1):

Для начала создадим библиотеку под названием `Window Style`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`Я пишу на net.core 6`

Создадим словарь ресурсов `WindowStyle.xaml`

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    x:Class="WinStyles.WindowStyle"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WinStyles"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <!--Стиль для кнопок у заголовка-->
    <Style x:Key="TopPanelBtn" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border x:Name="root" Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=(local:WindowStyleDP.BackgroundCaption)}">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#EAEAEA" TargetName="root"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <!--Контент для кнопки развернуть окно-->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ContentBtnRestore">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Viewbox x:Key="MaximizedCop" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="12" Height="12">
                    <Path Stroke="#000000" StrokeThickness="1"
      Data="M8.77778 8.77778H11V1H3.22222V3.22222M8.77778 8.77778V3.22222H3.22222M8.77778 8.77778V11H1V3.22222H3.22222"></Path>
                </Viewbox>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Border x:Name="Normal" BorderBrush="#000000"  BorderThickness="1" Width="11" Height="11"></Border>
            <Viewbox x:Name="Maximized" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="12" Height="12">
                <Path Stroke="#000000" StrokeThickness="1"
                  Data="M8.77778 8.77778H11V1H3.22222V3.22222M8.77778 8.77778V3.22222H3.22222M8.77778 8.77778V11H1V3.22222H3.22222"></Path>
            </Viewbox>
        </Grid>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WindowState, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" Value="Maximized">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="Normal"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="Maximized"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>

    <!--Контент для кнопки свернуть окно-->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ContentBtnMinimize">
        <Viewbox Width="12" Height="2">
            <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.8"  StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeStartLineCap="Round">
                <Path.Data>M11 1L1 0.999935</Path.Data>
            </Path>
        </Viewbox>
    </DataTemplate>

    <!--Стиль для кнопки закрыть окно-->
    <Style x:Key="StyleBtnClose" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border x:Name="root" Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=(local:WindowStyleDP.BackgroundCaption)}">
                        <Viewbox Width="14" Height="12">
                            <Grid>
                                <Path x:Name="s1" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.8" StrokeStartLineCap="Round"  StrokeEndLineCap="Round" 
                                      Data="M1.3999 1.60447L10.3999 10.1951"></Path>
                                <Path x:Name="s2" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.8" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" 
                                      Data="M10.2003 1.40485L1.60034 10.3955" Cursor=""></Path>
                            </Grid>
                        </Viewbox>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F14C4C" TargetName="root"/>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FFFFFF" TargetName="s1"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FFFFFF" TargetName="s2"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    
    <!--Стиль окна Window-->
    <Style x:Key="CustomWindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
            <Setter.Value>
                <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="35"
                              GlassFrameThickness="-2"
                              NonClientFrameEdges="None"
                              ResizeBorderThickness="5"
                              UseAeroCaptionButtons="True" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#293955" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                    <Border x:Name="Title" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <AdornerDecorator Grid.Row="1">
                                <ContentPresenter/>
                            </AdornerDecorator>
                            <Grid Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="35" Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=(local:WindowStyleDP.BackgroundCaption)}">
                                <StackPanel x:Name="Buttons" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                                    <Button Name="btnMinimize" Style="{StaticResource TopPanelBtn}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ContentBtnMinimize}" Width="45" Command="{x:Static local:WindowStyle.MinimizeCommand}"></Button>
                                    <Button Name="btnRestore" Style="{DynamicResource TopPanelBtn}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ContentBtnRestore}" Width="45" Command="{x:Static local:WindowStyle.MaximizeRestoreCommand}"></Button>
                                    <Button Name="btnClose" Style="{StaticResource StyleBtnClose}" Width="45"  Command="{x:Static local:WindowStyle.CloseCommand}" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"></Button>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <!--Тригер срабатывает при разворачивание окна на весь экран и для панели с к онтентом задаётся BorderThickness равный толщине системной рамке-->
                        <Trigger Property="WindowState" Value="Maximized">
                            <Setter TargetName="Title" Property="BorderThickness" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.WindowResizeBorderThickness}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Стилю Window дадим название `CustomWindowStyle` чтобы применить стиль в нашем приложение. Если не указать стиль явно для окна он не применится. К примеру если мы удалим ключ `x:Key="CustomWindowStyle"` это не будет работать для типа Window, но в случае с Custom Control, не стандартным окном стиль подхватится из темы автоматически.
[В этом ответе примерно описано почему стили не будут работать для всех окон](https://stackoverflow.com/a/460750/13439618)

Так как мы переопределили стиль окно сейчас у нас пустое и удален заголовок, края для растягивания окна, кнопки заголовка.
Чтобы вернуть функции заголовка, перемещение за него, развертывание экрана по двойному клику и возможность растягивать окно добавим `WindowChrome` и зададим настройки как у меня в коде.
`ResizeBorderThickness` отвечает за толщину краев у окна за которое можно растянуть окно.
`CaptionHeight` устанавливает высоту заголовка за которое мы можем перемещать окно.
Aero эффекты я оставил включенными, `GlassFrameThickness` устанавливает системную тень у окна.

Далее создадим класс `WindowStyle.xaml.cs`

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WinStyles
{
    public partial class WindowStyle : ResourceDictionary
    {

        static WindowStyle()
        {
            CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(Window), new CommandBinding(MinimizeCommand, MinimizeExecuted));
            CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(Window), new CommandBinding(MaximizeRestoreCommand, MaximizeRestoreExecuted));
            CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(Window), new CommandBinding(CloseCommand, CloseExecuted));

        }
        public static readonly RoutedCommand MinimizeCommand = new("Minimize", typeof(WindowStyle));

        public static readonly RoutedCommand MaximizeRestoreCommand = new("MaximizeRestore", typeof(WindowStyle));

        public static readonly RoutedCommand CloseCommand = new("Close", typeof(WindowStyle));

        private static void MinimizeExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var window = (Window)sender;
            window.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
        }
        private static void MaximizeRestoreExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var window = (Window)sender;
            if (window.WindowState == WindowState.Normal)
            {
                window.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
            }
            else
            {
                window.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            }
        }
        private static void CloseExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var window = (Window)sender;
            window.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

В нём зарегистрируем команды для работы кнопок нашего стиля. Свернуть, развернуть окно, закрыть окно.
Можно было использовать события `Click` но тогда если переопределить стиль эти события останутся привязаны и придется их код весь прописать вручную. Лучше использовать команды)

Далее создадим последний класс для библиотеки, `WindowStyleDP`
Его создавать не обязательно, он в качестве примера что в стиль можно пробросить attached свойства и ими легко настраивать внешний вид для стиля не заглядывая в шаблон после реализации.
Код

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows;

namespace WinStyles
{
public class WindowStyleDP
{
#region BackgroundCaption цвет фона заголовка окна
public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundCaptionProperty =
DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
nameof(GetBackgroundCaption)[3..],
typeof(SolidColorBrush),
typeof(WindowStyleDP),
new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#293955"))));

```
    public static SolidColorBrush GetBackgroundCaption(UIElement element) => (SolidColorBrush)element.GetValue(BackgroundCaptionProperty);

    public static void SetBackgroundCaption(UIElement element, SolidColorBrush value) => element.SetValue(BackgroundCaptionProperty, value);
    #endregion
}
```

}

Приступим к созданию проекта для проверки задачи.
Создадим проект `WindowsStyle_Sample`
В него добавим нашу библиотеку и подключим её в

`App.xaml`

```
 <Application x:Class="WindowsStyle_Sample.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WindowsStyle_Sample"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WinStyles;component/WindowStyle.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Запускаем проект, видим что тема применилась успешно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь переопределим тему для этого в дизайнере выберем окно Window и создадим копию шаблона
В коде можно нажать на код который принадлежит окну Window и я нажму на пкм в любом месте кроме самого окна чтобы не выбралась Grid.
В ресурсах window создалась копию нашего шаблона. Если пробовать запустить, то это работать не будет, так как стиль окна объявляется до проверки ресурсов окна. Поэтому код шаблона и сгенерированное пространство имён нужно перенести в App.xaml или создать словарь ресурсов и использовать переопределённый стиль.
Пример был с созданием стиля в библиотеки. Для кастомного окна все действия одинаковые кроме вызова окна в основном приложение.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]